# Django legacy database: is --fake-initial required if managed=false?

Tags: django, django-models

I am migrating a model which already has a table in a legacy database.

If I specify `managed = False` in that model's `Meta` class, is it still mandatory to use `--fake-initial` when executing the first `migrate` command?

Based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed), my understanding of `managed = False` is that Django would anyway not create any table, so `--fake-initial` seems redundant. Are there any other reasons `--fake-initial` should be used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **managed = False** property tells Django not to create the table as part of migrate command and not to delete it after flush. The catch here is that Django won't create the table during testing either. So if you wanted to test your code against non-production database you would get no table error. With managed = True and running first migration using **--fake-inital** Django won't create new tables but when testing you would be able to create test database.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to make some changes in the future, you wouldn't be able to auto-migrate your legacy table using Django if you have `managed=False`.